# Android : how to add a navigation drawer (sliding menu) inside only one of the tabs?

Tags: android, fragment

I have main Activity from this tab fragment calling
tab fragment has three tabs

three tabs A, B, C On click Tab b show only Navigation Drawer

Comment: You can disable the Navigation Drawer if current tab is A or C

Answer (score 0):

simply make the navigation drawer as an element of fragment 2 only,instead of defining it in the activity,define it inside fragment two

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the navigation drawer using:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
```

OR you can also use it if you are using custom navigation icon:

```
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(null);
```

through fragment interaction interface you can pass info from fragment to activity